# Python - dynamically calling a method with a dynamic number of arguments. Reflection?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, reflection

Say I want to parse a text file that has lines:

```
sampleMethod 
sampleParameter
sampleParameter2
```

where sampleMethod is a string of a method and sample parameters can be any type values.

I know I can use getattr to dynamically call something givn we know the module and method name:

```
output = getattr(componentName, sampleMethod)(sampleParameter)
```

but how can I do this if there are multiple parameters we discover dynamically?

So for example if the text file has:

```
sampleMethod 
sampleParameter
sampleParameter2
sampleParameter3
```

how can we do someting like this dynamically?

```
  output = getattr(componentName, sampleMethod)(sampleParameter, sampleParameter2, sampleParameter3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) your argument lists (the special *) :

```
# you could dynamically build the list 
parameterList = [sampleParameter, sampleParameter2, sampleParameter3]

# then pass as parameter
output = getattr(componentName, sampleMethod)(*parameterList)
```

Note that you do not have to use [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) if you are sure that `parameterList` will not be bigger than the number of parameters of `sampleMethod` (otherwise you can get an runtime error).

If you are not sure, you can still just slice the list first or use arbitrary argument lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use * in the attribute of the function definition. It will treat all argument which are not matched into a tuple. For example:

```
def print_for(*args):
    print args

print_for(1,2,3)
print_for(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

inputParams = ["1st_param", "2nd_param", ....]
module=SourceFileLoader("module_name","absolute/path/to/pyfile").load_module()
method = getattr(module, "functionname")
result = method(*inputParams)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).